# How to get first 8 char and last 8 char from string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

How to get first 8 char and last 8 char from srting using javascript ?

I use this code for php , How can i apply this code to javascript ?

```
$file_name_length = mb_strlen($file_name, 'UTF-8');
$first_char_position_last_8_char_file_name= $file_name_length-8;
$first_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name, 0, 8,"utf-8");
$last_8_char_file_name_display = mb_substr($file_name, $first_char_position_last_8_char_file_name, 8,"utf-8");
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried to write in JS so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var data = '12345678whatever87654321';

data.substr(0, 8); // 12345678
data.substr(-8); // 87654321
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with substring like this:

```
var str = "some string with many chars";
var newstr=str.substring(0,8)+str.substr(str.length-8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

In your case this should work:

```
var string = 'Hello nice nice world';

// with substring
console.log(string.substring(0, 8), string.substring(string.length - 8, string.length)); // Hello ni ce world

// with slice
console.log(string.slice(0, 8), string.slice(string.length - 8, string.length)); // Hello ni ce world
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same variable names you will have:

```
var file_name_length = file_name.length;
var first_char_position_last_8_char_file_name= file_name_length - 8;
var first_8_char_file_name_display = file_name.substr(0, 8);
var last_8_char_file_name_display = file_name.substr(first_char_position_last_8_char_file_name, 8);
```